# How to compute the gradient of the $2$-norm of this trigonometric function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields

I wonder how to compute the gradient of the following scalar field

$$L(x) :=  \| \sin \left( W_2 \cos \left( W_1 x \right) \right) \|_2^2,$$

where $r \in [1, 95]$, $W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times 100}$ and $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times r}$.

---

To begin with,

$$\nabla  L(x) = 2\sin(W_2 \cos(W_1 x))\cos(W_2 \cos(W_1 x)) A ,$$

where I consider $\sin(\cdot) \cos(\cdot)$ as vector consisting of element-wise product of the corresponding vectors, but I do not understand how to expand $A$ further (by $A$ I denote some placeholder for remains of the expression)

Comment: What is $x$????

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let's use the symbol $(\odot)$ to denote the elementwise/Hadamard product and a colon (:) to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
NB: when applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ this reduces to the standard dot product.

The Frobenius and Hadamard products commute
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C) = (A\odot B):C = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$
Furthermore, the properties of the underlying trace function allow the
terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in several different
but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$
Now consider the following cascade of vector variables
$$\eqalign{
a &= {W_1x} &\qiq da = W_1\,dx \\
s &= \sin(a),\;y = \cos(a) &\qiq dy = -s\odot da \\
b &= {W_2y} &\qiq db = W_2\,dy \\
c &= \cos(b),\;z = \sin(b) &\qiq dz = c\odot db \\
}$$
Use the definitions above to write the objective,
then calculate its differential and gradient

(mostly by back-substitution).
$$\eqalign{
L &= z:z \\
dL &= 2z:dz \\
 &= 2z:\LR{c\odot db} \\
 &= 2\LR{c\odot z}:db \\
 &= 2\LR{c\odot z}:\LR{W_2\,dy} \\
 &= 2W_2^T\LR{c\odot z}:dy \\
 &= 2W_2^T\LR{c(b)\odot z}:\LR{-s\odot da} \\
 &= -2s\odot\LR{W_2^T\LR{c\odot z}}:da \\
 &= -2s\odot\LR{W_2^T\LR{c\odot z}}:\LR{W_1\,dx} \\
 &= -2W_1^T\BR{s\odot\LR{W_2^T\LR{c\odot z}}}:dx \\
\grad{L}{x}
 &= -2W_1^T\BR{s\odot\LR{W_2^T\LR{c\odot z}}} \\
}$$
If you wish, you can continue the substitutions all the way back to the original variables, but the parentheses become so deeply nested that it starts to look like a snippet of LISP
$$\eqalign{
\grad{L}{x}
 &= -2W_1^T\BR{\sin({W_1x})\odot\LR{W_2^T\LR{\cos(W_2\cos({W_1x}))\odot\LR{\sin({W_2\cos({W_1x})})}}}} \\
}$$
An alternate approach, which *avoids* parentheses, is to replace the vector Hadamard products with diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
C &= \Diag{c} \\
S &= \Diag{s} \\
\grad{L}{x} &= -2W_1^T{S{W_2^T{Cz}}} \\
}$$